# ANTD table Print using ReactToPrint component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, antd, react-to-print

I am trying to print ANTD table using ReactToPrint hook, everything seems to work fine, but I want to show some text on top of page before print.
means I want to show some text for header purpose, when I am setting the visibility of header component true, its not print on first click, it shows on 2nd click, but I want to show the header on first click and when I print or cancel, header should be hide.

Please help me, Please hit print button two time to see the result in the below link.

https://codesandbox.io/s/usestate-not-updating-data-when-passing-from-parent-functional-component-using-r-forked-xuhnl

Thanks in Advance

Comment: While providing an external link is fine, your question should be self-contained and preferably not rely on external resources to be answered. Please add the relevant code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

When the `handlePrint` function is called, the ref `componentRef` points to the previous version of the component. `printHeaderVisible` only becomes true at the time of the next render.

You can try to postpone the print call until the next render like this

```
const reactToPrintFunc = useReactToPrint({
  content: () => componentRef.current,

  onBeforeGetContent: () => setprintHeaderVisible(true),
  onAfterPrint: () => setprintHeaderVisible(false)
});

const handlePrint = () => {
  setTimeout(reactToPrintFunc, 0);
};
```

or do as advised in [this issue](https://github.com/gregnb/react-to-print/issues/315#issuecomment-729131525)

```
const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
  content: () => componentRef.current,

  onBeforeGetContent: () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setprintHeaderVisible(true);
      resolve();
    });
  },
  onAfterPrint: () => setprintHeaderVisible(false)
});
```

Comment: Booom Booom! Thank you very much Andrey!